# Spring Fox (Swagger-UI) 2.9.2 How to disable the 'Try it out' button

Tags: firefox, swagger-ui

I am trying to disable the 'Try it out' button from the UI.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my Java class, I am doing something like below in an attempt to disable the button, and none of the properties I am trying seem to work. How can I disable the 'Try it out' button?

```
@GetMapping(path = "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object uiConfig() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    1. map.put("supportedSubmitMethods", new String[0]);
    2. map.put("x-explorer-enabled", Boolean.FALSE);
    3. map.put("x-samples-enabled", Boolean.FALSE);
    ...
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below code worked for me

```
@Bean
UiConfiguration uiConfig()
{
    return new UiConfiguration( null, UiConfiguration.Constants.NO_SUBMIT_METHODS );
}
```

Thanks